# SMART-Test never finishes. What can be done to let them complete?

Tags: hard-drive, smart, maintenance

When running SMART-Tests using `smartmontools`, they *never* finish. I always get "Interrupted (host reset.)" on various different systems and disks, including Debian in x86 and ARM, OS X on x64, with external and internal drives.

Even when run in captive mode with disks all empty (zeroed with `dd`).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your not doing anything wrong you.  Its the hardware that isn't working

Comment: Is it meant to work at all?

Comment: Yes it should be working

Comment: @MaxRied, are you saying you've tried this on lots of different computers with logs of different disks, and still never seen a completion, even for disks that you know to be healthy from a differant SMART analysis tool?

Comment: @FrankThomas Yes.

Answer (score 20):

When the drive does not handle any input/output activity during the test, it may go to standby, which raises the `Interrupted (host reset)` condition. Try to read from the disk at suitable intervals:

```
while true; do dd if=/dev/disk1 of=/dev/null count=1; sleep 60; done
```

(replace `/dev/disk1` with the appropriate device; reads one sector from that device every 60 seconds until you hit `ctrl-c`)

This helped in my environment: OS X 10.6.8, WD Elements USB-connected drive, SAT-SMART-driver 0.8.

A captive test should theoretically keep the drive online. Yet the hardware command send by `smartctl` may time out before the test completes, causing the kernel to reset the link and ending up in the same situation as above ([bug #303](http://www.smartmontools.org/ticket/303)).

See [this thread](http://sourceforge.net/p/smartmontools/mailman/smartmontools-support/thread/539B7800.9040001@obluda.cz/) on the smartmontools-support mailing list for further details. I acknowledge Christian Franke for the insight given here.

Comment: Other possible interruptions (http://serverfault.com/a/584055/): a bad cable can cause timeouts, and the kernel will trigger a reset.  I'm less sure it's necessary to stop smartd.  Any timeouts and interruptions will appear in dmesg/kern.log/`journalctl -fk`.

Comment: Wow, that's nuts!  Confirming - after dropping a HGST HDN726060ALE610 from a zpool mirror, it was stuck at 10% for 36 hours (it'll finish faster without other activity, RIGHT?).  Five minutes of these tiny dd reads caused it to finish.  Skepticism dismissed.

Comment: When I did my test on a 14TB Elements USB drive without the `dd` it endet with 90% still to go. Now it is at 10% to go since four hours, already. Temperature is at 49°C. I just changed the `dd` to `watch` from GreatEmerald's answer but I am not confident it will change anything.

Answer (score 12):

A variation on [Ari's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1294266/167207) is to use `watch`, because the `smartctl` output may in fact be interesting to keep track of the status:

```
sudo watch -d -n 60 smartctl -a /dev/sdx
```

This will auto-update the output of `smartctl -a` every 60 seconds, so you can see how much of the self-test time remains, and highlight the changes (so it's easier to spot that the test is indeed progressing).

Comment: `sudo watch -d -n 60 'smartctl -a /dev/sdX | grep "Self-test execution" -A 1'` greps to only the interesting lines.

Comment: Or `watch -d -n 60 smartctl --log=selftest /dev/sdx` for more context.

Answer (score 5):

I tried the [solution from sve.g](https://superuser.com/a/798946/167207), in my case the I kept finding the external USB drive in sleep mode regardless sometime after starting the test and interrupting it, it seems dd ended up reading from a kernel cache and the cache was large enough for the disk to enter sleep mode.

I noticed that calling smartctl to ask for status was always able to "wake up" the disk.
So: this version of the same idea did the trick for me:

```
sudo bash -c 'while true; do smartctl -a /dev/sdb > /dev/null; sleep 60; done'
```

After 5 hours the external USB disk is still spinning. For the first time I could see a smartctl long test finish in an external disk.

I believe this solution also has the advantage that the disk heads are not moved unnecesarily every minute.
The long run finished almost exactly in the predicted time (the keep-awake script did not add time to the run)

Answer (score 2):

The captive test may not work if it takes more than 20 seconds.

Source: ticket #[303](https://www.smartmontools.org/ticket/303), titled "In smart test captive mode, extend the timeout as described by the ATA device".

Answer (score 1):

As [GreatEmerald noted](https://superuser.com/a/1479731/167207), probing the smart data every few minutes keeps external USB drives from going to sleep. I wrote a script that checks the smart data every 5 minutes, until the test has exited.

I rely on the "Self-test execution status" code to check if the Smart test has completed. This script needs to run as root.

`smartctl -a $DEVICE | grep "Self-test execution status" | cut -d "(" -f2 | cut -d ")" -f1` extracts the status code of the self test. This has been tested with `smartctl` version 7.3

You'll need to edit the line that specifies the device UUID. You can find the UUID of your device using the command `ls /dev/disk/by-id`

```
#!/bin/bash

# SMART test status reference
# 240 to 250 - test running
# 0 - The previous self-test routine completed without error
# 33 - The self-test routine was interrupted by the host with a hard or soft reset

# This script runs a SMART long test and prevents the disk from going to sleep until the test has completed
# Probing a drive with smartctl seems to keep it spinning

DEVICE="/dev/disk/by-id/usb-WD_Elements_2621_575835324136314656444C4E-0:0"
smartctl -t long $DEVICE >/dev/null 2>&1
STATUS=$(smartctl -a $DEVICE | grep "Self-test execution status" | cut -d "(" -f2 | cut -d ")" -f1)

while [ $STATUS -gt 240 ]
do
  sleep 300
  STATUS=$(smartctl -a $DEVICE | grep "Self-test execution status" | cut -d "(" -f2 | cut -d ")" -f1)
done
```