# How to execute an Extended SMART self-test on a hard drive in Windows?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, smart

I have an old internal IDE hard drive that needs to be tested.  I used an IDE-to-USB adapter to connect it to a USB port on a Windows PC.  Then I tried using [GSmartControl](https://gsmartcontrol.sourceforge.io/home/) to execute the Short SMART self-test on the drive, and that worked fine.  Then I tried multiple times to execute an Extended SMART self-test on the drive, and each time it would run for 3-15 minutes before returning an "Interrupted (host reset)" error.  I tried running the Extended SMART self-test using [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) and got the same error.

I thought perhaps it was an issue with the USB port going to sleep.  In Device Manager, I noticed all of my "USB Root Hub" devices had the "Allow the computer to turn off the device to save power" option checked.  I unchecked all of them and rebooted.  But the Extended self-tests still returned "Interrupted (host reset)".

I came across a [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/766943/smart-test-never-finishes) on this site.  Apparently the drive can go into standby during the Extended self-test which causes the "Interrupted (host reset)" error.  The answers on that question suggest to periodically access the drive during the test - but they are UNIX-based solutions.

How can I periodically access the drive in Windows?  When the drive is connected, it does not get a drive letter assigned to it.  The drive was taken out of a RAID setup, so Windows does not recognize it.  Disk Management shows the drive but says it has an "Unknown" format.

Comment: Why don't you format the disk so it gets a proper drive letter?

Comment: @harrymc Because the PC that disk came from had a file system problem and I want to scan the disk to make sure there are no bad sectors.  I do not want to lose the data on the disk.

Comment: If you have problems with S.M.A.R.T. (which is in any case somewhat limited on IDE-to-USB), you could try a conventional disk test scan.

Comment: I ended up using the UBCD Live CD which has gsmartcontrol on it.  I guess it's not possible to read from a drive in Windows if it doesn't have a drive letter assigned to it?

Comment: Zero answers? Bummer, this is exactly the question I have, too.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into the same problem, I'm going to try this:
https://www.thewindowsclub.com/prevent-hard-drive-going-sleep-windows